# onResponseError Nuxt 3 + ohmyfetch

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

on submit, if the tokens are valid, everything works correctly and Swal displays a message, if the token is not valid, a refresh fires, the form submit fires again, but Swal no longer displays a message. How to deal with it?

```
 async onResponseError(ctx: FetchContext): Promise<any> {
    if (ctx.response.status === 401) {
      const { error } = await this.refreshToken();

      if (!error) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-await
        return await this.fetcher(ctx.request, ctx.options);
      }
    }
  }
```

repository

```
async addProductToCart(body: any, filter: any = {}): Promise<any> {
    return this.fetcher(this.urlGenerator.addProductToCart(), {
      method: 'POST',
      body,
      params: filter
    });
  }
```

my function

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async () => {
    const {
      error,
      pending
    } = await useLazyAsyncData(
      'updateUserProfile',
      () => httpRepository.addProductToCart(form),
      {
        initialCache: false
      }
    );

    isLoading.value = pending.value;

    if (!error.value) {
      Swal.fire({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-right',
        text: 'Данные успешно обновлены!',
        icon: 'success',
        timer: 3000,
        showConfirmButton: false
      });
    }
  });
```